# How to declare scalar table type?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[crudValues]
    @tblValue as dbo.tblValue READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE Value SET Value.Value = @tblValue.Value, Value.LastUpdate = @tblValue.LastUpdate FROM Value INNER JOIN @tblValue ON Value.ID = @tblValue.ID
END
```

When i execute this stored procedure it gives me the error

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure crudValues, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@tblValue".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure crudValues, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@tblValue".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure crudValues, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@tblValue".
```

How can i declare scalar table type. or how can i fix this error?

Comment: Did you create the "dbo.tblValue" table type?

Comment: Yes i did. It is in my user defined table types folder

Comment: change `ON Value.ID = @tblValue.ID` into `ON Value.ID = [@tblValue].ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either enclose the table variable in double-quotes or in brackets (but not in the join) or use an alias for the table variable in the query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[crudValues]
    @tblValue dbo.tblValue READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE Value 
    SET Value.Value = t.Value, Value.LastUpdate = t.LastUpdate 
    FROM Value INNER JOIN @tblValue t ON Value.ID = t.ID
END
```

The alternatives with quoted identifiers would look like: `[@tblValue].ID` or `"@tblValue".ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the table. This code produces the same error:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
        Field INT
)

SELECT 
    @Table.Field
FROM @Table
```